# Accidently zero-filled usb

Tags: usb

For a school project we had to zero-fill a computers hard drive. A classmate lent my usb because it contained the program CopyWipe. Instead of wiping the hard drive he accidently wiped my usb. Now I cannot use the USB anymore. I tried to format it but ofcourse that does not work. Is there a way to fix my USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some low-level format, like this: http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/ Free version should be enough for you.

After that remove, reinsert and do PROPER, FULL FORMAT. Not the quick one!